# get all the values from terraform for_each block in output

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to fetch the private ip address from the below terraform block.

```
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint_openAI" {
  for_each                            = var.private_endpoint_landing_zone_pe  
  provider                            = azurerm.sub_private_endpoint_landing_zone 
  name                                = each.key
  custom_network_interface_name       = "${each.key}-nic"
  location                            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name                 = each.value.rg_name
  subnet_id                           = each.value.subnet_id
  tags                                = each.value.tags
  private_service_connection {
    name                              = "${each.key}-svc-conn"
    private_connection_resource_id    = var.private_endpoint_landing_zone_openAI_id 
    is_manual_connection              = each.value.private_service_connection.is_manual_connection
    subresource_names                 = each.value.private_service_connection.subresource_names 
  }
  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = each.value.private_dns_zone_group.name
    private_dns_zone_ids = each.value.private_dns_zone_group.private_dns_zone_ids
  }
  depends_on                          = [azurerm_resource_group.rg]
}
```

Since the for_each is set, i am struggling to fetch the ip address values.

```
output "private_endpoint_interface_ip" {
  value = azurerm_private_endpoint.private_endpoint_openAI[*].private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address
}
```

I am getting below error.

```
This object does not have an attribute named "private_service_connection".
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You're passing this private_connection_resource_id    = var.private_endpoint_landing_zone_openAI_id  incorrectly which results in the error not because of using 'foreach' pass id parameter syntax correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have all the IP addresses in output, you cannot use the [splat (`*`) operator](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat#splat-expressions-with-maps) for that since `for_each` creates a map. You can however use [`values` built-in function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/values):

```
output "private_endpoint_interface_ip" {
  value = values(azurerm_private_endpoint.private_endpoint_openAI)[*].private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried accessing the private IP address of nic for a particular resource using Terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

When you have a `for_each` loop in your Terraform configuration for creating multiple resources based on a collection and you need to pass a specific attribute like `private_connection_resource_id` that varies for each iteration, you need to ensure that the attribute value is correctly mapped from your input variable to each resource instance.

```
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "private_endpoint_openAI" { 
...
for_each = var.private_endpoint_landing_zone_openAI
...
   private_service_connection {
   ..
   private_connection_resource_id = each.value.private_endpoint_landing_zone_openAI
   ..
}
```

I tried a demo test configuration and I tried to fetch the Private IP associated with the NIC of the storage resource.

**My terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# Fetch the existing resource group
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name = "demovksb-rg"
}

# Fetch the existing virtual network
data "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "virtnetvk"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

# Fetch the existing subnet
data "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "subnetvk"
  virtual_network_name = data.azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}


# Create the Private Endpoint
resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "example" {
  name                = "testvksam-privateendpoint"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  custom_network_interface_name = "testvksam-nic"
  subnet_id = data.azurerm_subnet.example.id

  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "testvkbb-privateserviceconnection"
    private_connection_resource_id = "/subscriptions/Subscrption_ID/resourceGroups/demovksb-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/testsbsamvksb" # Replace {subscription-id} and {storage-account-name} with actual values
    is_manual_connection           = false
    subresource_names              = ["blob"]
  }
}



# Output the private endpoint's private IP address (for the storage account connection)
output "private_endpoint_private_ip" {
  value = azurerm_private_endpoint.example.private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]